# finding difficulty in setting expandable listView settin OnClick listener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablelistview

I have created an expandable listview using recyclerView. I am unable to get the correct items in the recyclerView, the item at position 1 an 5 respond to same clicklistener.

ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.java

```
protected Context mContext;
protected List<T> allItems = new ArrayList<>();
protected List<T> visibleItems = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<>();
private SparseIntArray expandMap = new SparseIntArray();
private int mode;

protected static final int TYPE_HEADER = 1000;

private static final int ARROW_ROTATION_DURATION = 150;

public static final int MODE_NORMAL = 0;
public static final int MODE_ACCORDION = 1;

public ExpandableRecyclerAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

public static class ListItem
{
    public int ItemType;
    public ListItem(int itemType)
    {
        ItemType = itemType;
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i)
{
    return i;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return visibleItems == null ? 0 : visibleItems.size();
}

protected View inflate(int resourceID, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    return LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(resourceID, viewGroup, false);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
    }
}

public class HeaderViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    ImageView arrow;

    public HeaderViewHolder(View view, final ImageView arrow) {
        super(view);

        this.arrow = arrow;

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                handleClick();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void handleClick() {
        if (toggleExpandedItems(getLayoutPosition(), false)) {
            openArrow(arrow);

        } else {
            closeArrow(arrow);
        }
    }

    public void bind(int position) {
        arrow.setRotation(isExpanded(position) ? 90 : 0);
    }
}

public boolean toggleExpandedItems(int position, boolean notify) {
    if (isExpanded(position)) {
        collapseItems(position, notify);
        return false;
    } else
    {
        expandItems(position, notify);

        if (mode == MODE_ACCORDION)
        {
            collapseAllExcept(position);
        }

        return true;
    }
}

public void expandItems(int position, boolean notify)
{
    int count = 0;
    int index = indexList.get(position);
    int insert = position;

    for (int i=index+1; i<allItems.size() && allItems.get(i).ItemType != TYPE_HEADER; i++)
    {
        insert++;
        count++;

        visibleItems.add(insert, allItems.get(i));
        indexList.add(insert, i);
    }

    notifyItemRangeInserted(position + 1, count);

    int allItemsPosition = indexList.get(position);
    expandMap.put(allItemsPosition, 1);

    if (notify)
    {
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
}

public void collapseItems(int position, boolean notify)
{
    int count = 0;
    int index = indexList.get(position);

    for (int i=index+1; i<allItems.size() && allItems.get(i).ItemType != TYPE_HEADER; i++) {
        count++;
        visibleItems.remove(position + 1);
        indexList.remove(position + 1);
    }

    notifyItemRangeRemoved(position + 1, count);

    int allItemsPosition = indexList.get(position);
    expandMap.delete(allItemsPosition);

    if (notify)
    {
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
}

public class StaticViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    public StaticViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
    }
}

public class ItemViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    public ItemViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
    }
}

protected boolean isExpanded(int position) {
    int allItemsPosition = indexList.get(position);
    return expandMap.get(allItemsPosition, -1) >= 0;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return visibleItems.get(position).ItemType;
}

public void setItems(List<T> items) {
    allItems = items;
    List<T> visibleItems = new ArrayList<>();
    expandMap.clear();
    indexList.clear();

    for (int i=0; i<items.size(); i++) {
        if (items.get(i).ItemType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            indexList.add(i);
            visibleItems.add(items.get(i));
        }
    }

    this.visibleItems = visibleItems;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

protected void notifyItemInserted(int allItemsPosition, int visiblePosition) {
    incrementIndexList(allItemsPosition, visiblePosition, 1);
    incrementExpandMapAfter(allItemsPosition, 1);

    if (visiblePosition >= 0) {
        notifyItemInserted(visiblePosition);
    }
}

protected void removeItemAt(int visiblePosition) {
    int allItemsPosition = indexList.get(visiblePosition);

    allItems.remove(allItemsPosition);
    visibleItems.remove(visiblePosition);

    incrementIndexList(allItemsPosition, visiblePosition, -1);
    incrementExpandMapAfter(allItemsPosition, -1);

    notifyItemRemoved(visiblePosition);
}

private void incrementExpandMapAfter(int position, int direction) {
    SparseIntArray newExpandMap = new SparseIntArray();

    for (int i=0; i<expandMap.size(); i++) {
        int index = expandMap.keyAt(i);
        newExpandMap.put(index < position ? index : index + direction, 1);
    }

    expandMap = newExpandMap;
}

private void incrementIndexList(int allItemsPosition, int visiblePosition, int direction) {
    List<Integer> newIndexList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=0; i<indexList.size(); i++) {
        if (i == visiblePosition) {
            if (direction > 0) {
                newIndexList.add(allItemsPosition);
            }
        }

        int val = indexList.get(i);
        newIndexList.add(val < allItemsPosition ? val : val + direction);
    }

    indexList = newIndexList;
}

public void collapseAll() {
    collapseAllExcept(-1);
}

public void collapseAllExcept(int position) {
    for (int i=visibleItems.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (i != position && getItemViewType(i) == TYPE_HEADER) {
            if (isExpanded(i)) {
                collapseItems(i, true);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void expandAll() {
    for (int i=visibleItems.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (getItemViewType(i) == TYPE_HEADER) {
            if (!isExpanded(i))
            {
                expandItems(i, true);

            }
        }
    }
}

public static void openArrow(View view) {
    view.animate().setDuration(ARROW_ROTATION_DURATION).rotation(90);
}

public static void closeArrow(View view) {
    view.animate().setDuration(ARROW_ROTATION_DURATION).rotation(0);
}

public int getMode() {
    return mode;
}

public void setMode(int mode) {
    this.mode = mode;
}
```

PeopleAdapter.java

```
public static final int TYPE_PERSON = 1001;
static Activity context;
public PeopleAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context);
    PeopleAdapter.context = (Activity) context;
    setItems(getSampleItems());
}

public static class PeopleListItem extends ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.ListItem {
    public String Text;

    public PeopleListItem(String group) {
        super(TYPE_HEADER);

        Text = group;

    }

    public PeopleListItem(String first, String last) {
        super(TYPE_PERSON);
        Text = first + " " + last;
    }
}

public class HeaderViewHolder extends ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.HeaderViewHolder  {
    TextView name;

    public HeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view, (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_arrow));

        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_header_name);
    }

    public void bind(int position) {
        super.bind(position);

        name.setText(visibleItems.get(position).Text);
    }


}


public class PersonViewHolder extends ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    public PersonViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);

    }

    public void bind(int position) {
        name.setText(visibleItems.get(position).Text);
    }

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case TYPE_HEADER:
            return new HeaderViewHolder(inflate(R.layout.item_header, parent));
        case TYPE_PERSON:
        default:
            return new PersonViewHolder(inflate(R.layout.item_person, parent));
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case TYPE_HEADER:
            ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).bind(position);
            break;
        case TYPE_PERSON:
        default:
            ((PersonViewHolder) holder).bind(position);
            break;
    }
}

private List<PeopleListItem> getSampleItems() {
    List<PeopleListItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    items.add(new PeopleListItem("Friends"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("Bill", "Smith"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("John", "Doe"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("Frank", "Hall"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("Sue", "West"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("Family"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("Drew", "Smith"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("Chris", "Doe"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("Alex", "Hall"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("Alex", "Hall"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("Alex", "Hall"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("Associates"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("John", "Jones"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("Ed", "Smith"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("Jane", "Hall"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("Tim", "Lake"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("Colleagues"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("Carol", "Jones"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("Alex", "Smith"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("Kristin", "Hall"));
    items.add(new PeopleListItem("Pete", "Lake"));

    return items;
}
```

i have also created a recyclerView clicklistener

MainActivity.java

```
recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recycler.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    // TODO Handle item click
                    Log.e("@@@@@", "" + position);
                    switch (position)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            recycler.getFocusedChild();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) recycler.getFocusedChild(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),sample.class);
                            startActivity(in);
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"7",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            })
    );
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Expand you're bind method with a `setOnClickListener`.

```
public void bind(int position) {
    name.setText(visibleItems.get(position).Text);
    name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doSomething(visibleItems.get(position));
        }
    });
}
```